# Check if File changed in the last 30 mins on SFTP via Bash

Tags: server, bash, sftp

I need to look if a file changed in the last 30 mins, and if it didn't change, then exit the script.

There will be a directory with many files on the sftp server, but I only need to check if there is a file that changed within 30 Minutes. The code for this check is down below.

The script will be running as a cronjob every minute or so.

I have a simple if-sentence to look if the file changed, but it is not possible to run it on the sftp server.

```
if [ $(find ./ -type f -mmin 30) ]
```

My ubuntu version is 20.04, and it is not possible to run ssh on the sftp.

Is there a way, so I can run the if sentence straight on the sftp?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Please explain your situation more clearly in the question. Why do you want to run this on a sftp server? Can you ssh to this server?

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1320832/edit) and add the full code of what you want to do if the file has changed along with the information I had asked for before.

Comment: Your titles says "*a file*", but your script seems more to be like "*any file on the server*" Please clarify!

Comment: I have edited my article now. Sorry for this little information, at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run expressions like `if` or `find` via `sftp` directly. You would need to use [`sftp` commands](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sftp.1.html#INTERACTIVE_COMMANDS) and parse the information yourself from their output or use `python` `pysftp` to programm it yourself.

However, you can mount the `sftp` server and run your `find` locally on the mounted directory:

```bsh
# Install sshfs on your localcomputer if needed
sudo apt install sshfs

# Mount the directory
mkdir sftpmnt
sudo sshfs -o allow_other -p 60022 user@server:/ sftpmnt/

# List all files changed within the last 30 minutes
find sftpmnt -mmin -30 -printf '%T+\t%p\n'

# Or check if any file changed within the last 30 minutes and do_something
if find sftpmnt -mmin -30 -print -quit | grep -q "." ; then
   echo "Found new or modified file(s)"
   do_something
fi
```